# I have created a loop which writes variables for 8 rivers. I now want to get the mean and the standard deviation of these variables?

Tags: loops, mean, standard-deviation

I have created a loop which writes a river lengths for 8 rivers. I now want to get the mean and the standard deviation of these variables however i can only access the last river length. Is there a way i can use each river length separately

Comment: Check out [ask] and [mcve] and then come back to edit your question.

Comment: Funny how you used a question mark after a statement, but omitted it after your question.

Comment: I don't like being patronised :( i'm really struggling trying to learn python and would really appreciate some help. I was informed that this was the best site to use as people gave friendly advice.. i was evidently wrong